# JS Diffie Hellman SSL with blockchain auth

Tags: javascript, encryption, blockchain, diffie-hellman

I'm trying to figure out if the security quality of SSL can be mimicked without the need for a centralized CA.

There are many questions on here about setting up pure-JS diffie hellman in place of SSL. All of them are roundly refuted, and I think I understand why (although I completely disagree that there's no value in DH-keyed symmetric encryption for the millions of sites which are not going to be implementing full SSL anytime soon either way).

Anyway, question is this: it seems as though the only preventative reason JS DH wouldn't work is that you lose authentication so you're still subject to man-in-the-middle. All the [myriad other issues](https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/august/javascript-cryptography-considered-harmful/) flow from attempts to resolve this one.

But what if you used a blockchain as a certificate authority? The process would then be

1. Form DH key
2. encrypt any handshake string with known public key from blockchain
3. encrypt this verify string with DH key
4. if handshake string received back, authentication verifies and DH is as secure as SSL DH

**Edit:** didn't mean to imply DH was symmetric, adjusted for clarity

Comment: Yay blockchain hype train. Great that you're trying to figure that out but maybe you don't want to use JavaScript?

Comment: Choo choo! :) Why not use JS though? I'm a big fan of atwood's law, and have come across a couple proofs of concept for the DH component based on Leemon Baird's BigInt lib, so far it seems viable...